# How to delete rows and columns from an associative NxN matrix in O(n) in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, runtime, associative

I have an associative NxN matrix and a vector containing all columns:

```
std::map<std::string,std::map<std::string,int>> A;
std::vector<std::string> columns; //this has size n
```

An element would look like this: A["abc"]["bcd"] = 2

I want to remove the row "abc" (so basically `A["abc"]`) and the column "abc" (so basically `A[*]["abc"]`) in O(n)

```
A.erase("abc"); //this is O(log n)

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) //this is O(n*log n)
{
    A[words[i]].erase("abc"); 
}
```

This has O(n*log n) runtime. Is it possible to do it in O(n)?

Comment: How about using a `map<pair<string,string>,int>` instead?

Comment: `A[words[i]]` -- You need to be careful here.  This will add an empty entry in the map if `words[i]` doesn't exist in the map.

Comment: map<pair<string,string>,int> is a possibility but I stil can't delete row and column quicker than O(n*log n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int>`, where the pair of strings are the row and column values.

Then you can use the custom [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) algorithm that works on a `std::map`, which runs in `O(n)` time:

```
std::erase_if(A, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    return key.first == "abc" or key.second == "abc";
});
```

Comment: But the runtime is linear to the number of elements in the map which is n^2. Is it impossible to remove rows and columns in O(n)?

Comment: If you have `O(n^2)` elements, how do you expect to even look at all the elements in less than that time?

Comment: Because I know the rows and the columns

Comment: Well, a map lets you erase an element with a particular key in `O(log n)`, but you also want to remove other elements, which you can't really do any faster than looking at all the elements.

Comment: OK, so what I want is basically impossible. I need to pick a data structure which is ordered by the 2nd coordinate as well, so if I know which row and column need to be deleted I can do it without iterating through every other elements as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need to find the right data structure for your case.